# cordova/phonegap: command not found, elementaryOS Luna

Tags: node.js, cordova

I've ran into some problem with installing cordova and phonegap.
When i try to run `sudo npm install -g cordova` (same with phonegap). I got this result (for cordova)

```
/home/tomek/npm/bin/cordova -> /home/tomek/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@3.5.0-0.2.7 /home/tomek/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── q@0.9.7
├── underscore@1.4.4
├── nopt@2.2.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@0.21.7 (osenv@0.0.3, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.5, mime@1.2.11, semver@2.0.11, dep-graph@1.1.0, plist-with-patches@0.5.1, shelljs@0.1.4, xcode@0.6.6, npmconf@0.1.16, elementtree@0.1.5, glob@3.2.11, rc@0.3.0, tar@0.1.19, request@2.22.0, npm@1.3.4, cordova-js@3.6.2)
```

But when I later try to run `cordova` command it simply doesn't find this command.
What do I do wrong, and why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You may have your nodes confused, try the following in terminal:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

This install guide may help you: http://software-issues.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo.html, with your distro being ubuntu based you should have no problem following this. (Beware I forgot to sudo the npm command in the guide, must get around to editing that).